# I'm unable to use arrow key in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: command-line, keyboard

I'm very new to Ubuntu and Linux. I am trying to install VST plugins for a [DAW] called [Reaper]. In the terminal I am unable to select the "Yes" or "No" option during the terminal prompt. Can someone please help me easily understand and solve the issue?

I have attached screenshots of the prompt and the screenshot of the issue when I try to use the arrow keys to select option "Yes"

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you tried tab as mentioned by @Pilot6, it is possible that your terminal is not refreshing. Press Control+L (that's lowercase L btw), to see if it clears up. Otherwise, press Control+C and try again.

Comment: Well this is the tutorial video I'm referring to https://youtu.be/cG6ipmOyfw0

Comment: https://github.com/brendaningram/linux-audio-setup-scripts/blob/main/ubuntu/focal/install-audio-jack.sh

Comment: above is the link to the scripts

Comment: It is unlikely that this is related to that particular application because those screens are handled via standard terminal tools. Try what we suggested. If that still doesn't work, and Control+C is not stopping the application, you can always close the terminal and try again..

Answer (score 3):

Navigate  using <kbd>Tab</kbd> button, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I tried the tab key but it does not highlight the yes option

Comment: Press it again. Are you sure you are pressing Tab?